# How can I insert information from a referenced table into another table?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I need to create forms with multiple questions and insert data through knex.

I create the forms first with an id and an order number, after which I create the questions, which need to get id from the forms to be assigned correctly.

```js
// basic form insertion, id is generated automatically
return knex("forms").insert([
  { title: "Form 1 title", order: "1"} // id = gen_random_uuid();
  // form2, form3...
]};

// form_id is referenced for questions
return knex("questions").insert([
  {
    form_id: "???",
    title: "Question 1",
    order: "1"
  }
]);
```

My idea is to use select and where, but I couldn't get them working.

`return knex.select("id").from("forms").where("order", "1")`

PS. I actually need to get pages --> their id to assign forms --> their id to assign questions correctly. But if I get this working, it'll probably be just one step more after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell knew to return the generated ID, see: https://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning

You can then use the returned ID for your second insert.

Example:

```js
knex("forms").returning("id").insert([
  { title: "Form 1 title", order: "1"} // id = gen_random_uuid();
  // form2, form3...
]}
  .then(function(rows) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      knex("questions").insert([
        {
          form_id: rows[i].id,
          title: "Question 1",
          order: "1"
        }
      ])
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! Took a bit of figuring out, but finally understood that the rows mean the returning value that the forms bring in this scenario. Got it working now!